# Removing repeated and really redundant namespaces

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, namespaces, xquery

In the following code this statement;

```
declare namespace pd="http://cargowise.com/ediEnterprise/2011/10/11/systemUsage.xsd
```

is repeated 6 times making the code really messy and harder to follow:

```
SELECT XW_PK, xw_ExeVersion, xw_enterpriseCode, xw_DatabaseCode, xw_CompanyCode,
    Poodle.Love.value('declare namespace pd="http://cargowise.com/ediEnterprise/2011/10/11/systemUsage.xsd";
    (pd:action/@name)[1]', 'varchar(100)') Name,
    Poodle.Love.value('declare namespace pd="http://cargowise.com/ediEnterprise/2011/10/11/systemUsage.xsd";
    (pd:action/@started)[1]', 'varchar(100)') [Started],
    Poodle.Love.value('declare namespace pd="http://cargowise.com/ediEnterprise/2011/10/11/systemUsage.xsd";
    (pd:action/@ended)[1]', 'varchar(100)') [Ended],
    Poodle.Love.value('declare namespace pd="http://cargowise.com/ediEnterprise/2011/10/11/systemUsage.xsd";
    (pd:action/@Elapsed)[1]', 'varchar(100)') Elapsed,
    Poodle.Love.value('declare namespace pd="http://cargowise.com/ediEnterprise/2011/10/11/systemUsage.xsd";
    (pd:action/@elapsedWithChildren)[1]', 'varchar(100)') elapsedWithChildren
    FROM   stmusage
        CROSS APPLY xw_rawData.nodes('declare namespace pd="http://cargowise.com/ediEnterprise/2011/10/11/systemUsage.xsd";
        /pd:performanceMeasurement/pd:action') as Poodle(Love)
```

What I want to do is declare the namespace just once and be done with it. The problem is that each of the xqueries are embedded in a string - and I'm not completely sure - but the experiece I've picked up over the years gives me the overwhelming impression that these strings aren't going to be interacting with each other any time soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
            XMLTable.actions.value('(@name)', 'varchar(100)') Name,
            XMLTable.actions.value('(@started)', 'datetime') [Started],
            XMLTable.actions.value('(@started)', 'datetime') + 
            convert(float, replace (replace (XMLTable.actions.value('(@elapsedWithChildren)', 'varchar(100)'),'PT',''),'S','')) / (60 * 60 * 24) Ended, --dodgy floating point rounding errors
            convert(float, replace (replace (XMLTable.actions.value('(@elapsed)', 'varchar(100)'),'PT',''),'S','')) Elapsed,
            convert(float, replace (replace (XMLTable.actions.value('(@elapsedWithChildren)', 'varchar(100)'),'PT',''),'S','')) ElapsedWithChildren,
            XMLTable.actions.value('@moduleId','varchar(100)') moduleid,
            XMLTable.actions.value('@actionCount','int') actionCount,
            XW_PK, XW_ExeVersion, XW_EnterpriseCode, XW_DatabaseCode, XW_CompanyCode, ExportType
            FROM StmUsage
                CROSS APPLY xw_rawData.nodes('declare namespace pd="http://cargowise.com/ediEnterprise/2011/10/11/systemUsage.xsd";
                /pd:performanceMeasurement/pd:action') XMLTable(actions)
            cross join (select 'Elapsed' ExportType union select 'ElapsedWithChildren') ExportTypeAlias
```

Easy as!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the programming language you are writing in, but in any other language I would write a function that takes the string "name" or "started" as a parameter PPPPP and produces

Poodle.Love.value('declare namespace d="http://cargowise.com/ediEnterprise/2011/10/11/systemUsage.xsd";
    (pd:action/@{PPPPP})[1]', 'varchar(100)')

as its result.